# Dynamics Nav: Which tables are affected when creating an order via the SOAP API?

Tags: soap, navision, dynamics-nav

There are a lot of pages in NAV that have a reference to sales orders. See list below.

Which Pages do I need to populate if I want to create a customer orders via the API? I use NAV 2013 (not R2).

I have read elsewhere that these are only the pages salesorder_order and salesorder_orderline.

What about customer?

I use SOAP and C# and have no problems with writing and reading the API. I just don't know which tables to use.

List of pages related to orders:

- order_headers
- order_lines
- salesorder_list
- salesorder_orderSalesLines
- salesorder_order
- salesorder_orderline
- customer
- webshop_salesorder_order
- webshop_salesorder_orderline
- webshop_customer
- salescredit_credit
- salescredit_creditline
- salesinvoice_invoice
- salesinvoice_invoiceline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Order and OrderLine should be enough to create the order. Credit is when you creating the return for items previously sold, and Invoice is a posted order (not editable).

As for the customer, it depends whether you are willing to create customers or you are going to use some predefined one. Cuz customer is an essential field. So if you are going to create new customers you need to publish page for them as well. And this goes for any other entity that is related to order. Like Items or Accounts.

Basically you need to publish pages for everything you don't have defaults for. And this depends on what you have in external (to Nav) system.